# Out of browser and multiple windows

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

When you are using out of browser in silverlight are you trapped into a single window or can you open a second window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Silverlight 4 beta, you are trapped into a single window.  No word on RTM features, but it doesn't look likely.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 5 allows multiple windows for trusted applications:

> Trusted, out-of-browser applications that target Silverlight 5 can use the following features that are unavailable to earlier versions:
>
> Multiple windows. You can create additional Window instances to provide a more flexible user interface. For example, users can open parts of your application in separate windows, and then move those windows to a second monitor. You can also create modal dialog boxes and tear-off windows. For more information, see Window.
>
> Additional elevated trusted capabilities. In Silverlight 5, trusted applications can use PInvoke to call functions in unmanaged assemblies. Trusted applications also have greater access to the local file system. Additionally, system administrators can enable trusted applications to run inside the browser (although without the ability to use the Window class). For more information, see Trusted Applications.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=vs.95).aspx section "**Special Features for Out-of-Browser Applications**"